# How can I grep a region of a string?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have a file that contains more than 4000 characters and I want to grep the string between the position 148 and 1824. How can I do this?

Comment: You have a nice answer there from terdon hint hint https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

You don't use grep. There is a tool that has been designed for precisely this sort of thing: `cut`. To get characters 148 to 1824, do:

```
cut -c 148-1824 file
```

The `-c` flag means select characters. Use `-b` if you want to work on bytes.

If you insist on using `grep`, you would have to do something like this (assuming GNU grep)

```
grep -Po '^.{147}\K.{1675}' file
```

This matches the first 147 characters (`^.{147}`) and discards them (`\K`). Then it matches the next 1675 characters. The `-o` flag tells `grep` to only print the matching section of a line and the `-P` flag turns on perl-compatible regular expressions which let us use `\K`.

Answer (score 4):

The command below will do the same. I tested it and it works fine. It extracts all characters from the 148th to the 1824th position.

```
awk '{print substr($0,148,1676)}' filename
```

`substr($0,148,1676)}` will take a substring of the current line (`$0`), starting at the 148th character and continuing until the character at position 148 + 1676. That means it ends at position 1824.

Answer (score 1):

To "grep" against a subsection of each line in a file, use awk to extract that subsection and then compare that section against your regular expression.

A simplified example:

```
$ cat input
junkjeffjunk

$ awk '{ piece=substr($0, 5, 4); if (piece ~ /jeff/) print piece; }' input
jeff
```

For your case:

```
awk '{ piece=substr($0, 148, 1676); if (piece ~ /your-regex-here/) print piece; }' input
```